# Android - How to prevent admob reload each time activity open?

Tags: android

I have a list of articles, when user click on an item, it will show an activity with admob on it.
The problem is admob is reloaded every time.
How do I prevent admob from reloading?

Comment: Post your code where you are loading Ad

Comment: You at least have to show what you have tried, or where you have got error.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you enter the "Activity" banner admod reload banner that the activity is new.

Admob reloading banner for default each 60 seconds, you can change.